# How to check if string is palindrome in Assembly? [code help]

Tags: assembly

I never did Assembly and we just started it in school, professor gave us this code, but I didn't get something right and I don't know what.. can you see the problem?

```
.section .data
    status: .byte 1
    string_A: .ascii "kapak\0"
.section .text
.globl main
main:
    movl $0, %eax
    pushl $string_A
    call string
    addl $8,%esp

.type string, @function
string:
    pushl %ebp
    movl %esp, %ebp
    movl 8(%ebp), %esi
    movl %esi, %edi

    loop:
        movl $4, %esi
        cmpl $0, %esi
        jg petlja
    again:
        movb (%esi), %al
        cmpb (%edi), %al
        je uvecaj
        jne exit
    increase:
        addl $1, %edi
        addl $-1, %esi
        jmp again

    movl %ebp, %esp
    popl %ebp
    ret

exit:
    movl $1,%eax
    movl $0,%ebx
    int $0x80
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Asking people to spot errors in your code is not especially productive. You should use a debugger to isolate the problem, by tracing the progress of your program, and comparing it to what you expect to happen. As soon as the two diverge, then you've found your problem. (And then if necessary, you should construct a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org).)

Answer (score 1):

You should give a bit more info than that for us:

You need help with "assembly". Well, what assembly? I can guess you're writing for x86, but you might want to make that explicit in your question. Also, comment your code, especially in assembly. It's not made for people to read easily. Also, when you translate your code into English, translate all of it. Your jump-targets don't exist in your code.

Anyway, you're in luck because this program is simple enough to read some of it anyway:

In your `main()`-function, you call `string()` (which is a bad name...), but after `string()` returns, what happens? Right, the stack-pointer is increased by eight. Wait, **8**? But you only pushed a pointer in `pushl $string_A`! That's only 32-bits (or **4** bytes) on this 
architecture! -> Fail.

Even if that didn't blow up, after that you don't return or exit. You simply keep executing linearly... right into `string()`. So now string reads its pointer some 8 + 4 = **12** bytes from where it should be. That pointer could point anywhere, if the page access violation didn't already segfault.

I could try to reverse engineer where your jumps in `string()` should go, but you should really post readable code, so I won't.